# Excel crash when typing '?' in SQL ODBC request

Tags: sql, excel, odbc, excel-2013

Good morning, I have a big problem on Excel 2013 : when I want to add a parameter in an ODBC SQL request by typing '?', Excel crashes.

It also crashes when returning the request with parameter from Microsoft Query.

What I'm trying to do :

> Select * from X where date = ?

Then normally excel asks for the cell where the parameter is, but in my case excel crashes.

Does anybody has already solved this issue ?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: It should just work. I would start troubleshooting by defining everything that can be defined so there is less guesswork on the application's part. E.g. `where X.date = ?` instead of `where date = ?`

Comment: Select * from planning where date = ?

Comment: I think it's a driver or excel issue, I'll try with openoffice and another odbc driver maybe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel SQL Query from ODBC "Error - No Value given for one or more required parameters Excel SQL Query" When using \`WHERE XXX = ?\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35128339/excel-sql-query-from-odbc-error-no-value-given-for-one-or-more-required-param)